# Dialogfragment show function with same tag in every activity?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have six or seven activities where i use Dialogfragment at various places. Now i need to know that can we use the show function with same tag everywhere in the whole app?
Dialogfragment is from support lib.

```
 private Messagebox msg= new Messagebox();
```

initialized once and then everywhere, where Messagebox extends  Dialogfragment

```
msg.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "msg1");
```

Comment: "can we use the show function with same tag everywhere in the whole app?".  Elaborate and show us some code

Comment: @Raghunandan edited question.

Comment: You can use a singelton with dagger2 an inject dialog  code where ever you want. So having singleton will have only object of msg